# Is there a way to get metaStyles when converting docx to markdown with pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Is there a way to get word paragraphs with metaStyles (Title, Subtitle, Author, Date, Abstract) converted to markdown with `custom-style` attribute?

To reproduce it:

- A word document with a single paragraph "MyTitle" styled with "Title"

Without the `--standalone` option the metaStyles are ignored.
When using the `--standalone` option the metaStyles are exported to meta data in markdown as follows:

```
---
title: MyTitle
---
```

What I need is to get the following in markdown (for Title, Subtitle etc.):

```
::: {custom-style="Title"}
MyTitle
:::
```

I'd expect it when using `-f docx+styles` but this is only the case when the word document starts with a non-metaStyle paragraph!

To reproduce it:

- A word document with two paragraphs:

  - First paragraph "std" styled with "Standard"
  - Second paragraph "MyTitle" styled with "Title"